# All icon is missing from phpMyAdmin

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am able to create users, and all process.

But I don’t know why all icons is missing from phpmyadmin

[image]

As Well as see

[Another Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoIHp.png)

My pc is in a LAN and another user adds table in my phpmyadmin.
What’s the problem is here?
And my network tab is as follow

[Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgc3t.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you use firebug or similar, you can look at the error that occurs with the images. With this debug data, you can resolve it.

Comment: in chrome firebug is available

Comment: is called "developer tools" or "web developer" or you can inspect element and see "network" tab.

Comment: i also post network tab image @track3r . please help i still didn't solve this.